# How do I find in the source code a destroyed thread that were still waiting?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, debugging

I'm trying to identify exactly where and which file a thread that gets destroyed when the application is closed but that were still waiting. The debug message show this message:

> QThread(0x17aa2ea0)QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still
>   waiting

Is possible to get *where* in the source code (it's a large code base not wrote by me) this thread is started so that I can try to fix and exit it properly when no longer needed?

Answer (score 0):

I know that within VS you can Control + F to search. You can search for something within that message, such as QThread(0x17aa2ea0). Providing that the code is available to you and that this wait condition is within the code, you'll most likely be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple solution for that. My solution for such a problem is:

- Search for all `QWaitCondition` variables/class members
- Search for all classes that create threads and output a debug message with the thread id in each place (i.e. in constructor)
- Include an debug message with the thread id in each class destructor

Then you know what threads are created and where they are created. Of course, i you are using thread pools the thing is much more difficult.